# How to get distance from camera form world position and MVP matrix?

Tags: opengl, glsl

So in the context of a deferred renderer, I have a world position (vec3) and the MVP matrix of the scene camera.  Is it possible to get the distance from the camera (in world units) from this?

So far I have tried this:

```
vec4 projected = mvp * vec4(worldPosition);
float distanceFromCamera = projected.z / projected.w;
```

And it does not seem to be giving the correct result.

Comment: @Rabbid76: no, it is not.

Comment: Because the fourth column of `inverse(view)` is, which is a value which not only depends on the last column of `view`, but also the actual rotations.

Comment: @Rabbid76: if the view matrix were solely a translation, the fourth column would be the _negated_ view position. If you add rotations to the picture, the fourth column will be some _rotated_ and _negated_ form of the camera position. If the matrix is truly orthogonal, there then there can be no translation part, so then yes, the camera position would be by definition (0,0,0,1) if the view matrix is orthogonal.

Answer (score 3):

The *view* matrix transfroms points from *world space* to *eye space*. Assuming some sane eye space convention, the camera will be at `(0,0,0,1)` in eye space (a.k.a., eye space origin). So if you want the world space camera position, you can just use

```
cam_world = inverse(view) * vec4(0,0,0,1)
```

and use that to calculate the difference. Note that you can do this calculation in the CPU and just provide the result as uniform.

> So far I have tried this:
>
> ```
> vec4 projected = mvp * vec4(worldPosition);
> float distanceFromCamera = projected.z / projected.w;
> ```

That will calculate a value in normalized device space, with hyperbolically distorted z, scaled to the [-1,1] range. And it is actually not the distance to the camera, but the distance the camera plane (a plane which is parallel to the image plane and where the camera lies in).

> So in the context of a deferred renderer, I have a world position (vec3) and the MVP matrix of the scene camera. Is it possible to get the distance from the camera (in world units) from this?

So the actual answer is: no, not in the general case. If all you have is the composite transform `projection*view*model`, there is no way you can get world space information, this matrix goes directly from object space to clip space, bypassing world and view space completely.  Note that "MVP matrix of the scene camera" does not make sense, because `M` is not related to any camera at all.